# How many percent of variance can each variable explain in principal components analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, pca

In a dataset with 5 variables, how many percent of variance of the dataset can each variable explain at most?

Answer (score 1):

Each variable can explain between 0-100 % of the total variance, and together the sum of the explained variances must equal 100 %.